Will a partition key that has an incrementing int value fall within the same physical partition in Cosmos DB?
Let's say that I have a document of the following structure.
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "f_name": "Foo",
  "l_name": "Bar"
}

Let's say I assign user_id as the partition key. Also assume that the value for user ID is an incrementing integer. i.e. 1,2,3...N.
Will this result in documents with the user_ids that are close to one another being stored in the same physical partition? Or will then still be evenly distributed among the physical partitions?
i.e. would the documents containing user_ids within a range say 100,001 and 110,000 fall within the same physical partition?
The reason I ask this is, to wonder if 90% of my queries come from a specific range of user_ids, whether there's a possibility of a hot partition being formed.
Mongo DB's documentation explains how monotonically changing keys will be handled during sharding.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys
But couldn't find similar information on Cosmos DB.

CosmosDB is not MongoDB (eventhough it may provide a compatible interface). So it probably doesn't make to much sense, trying to transfer storepriciples or similar from one to the other.
See the docs on partitioning in CosmosDB
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview
Long story short: Your userid creates logical partitions (ie each unique userid creates a separate logical partition). And these logical partitions are distributed over (potentially many) physical partitions (but if you only have very few documents, it is possible that there is only a single physical partition) based on a hashing algorithm. So there is (at least for us as users) no way to predict

how many physical partitions will be used (as a rule of thumb, the more documents/logical partitions the more physical partitions)
which logical partitions will end up together in the same physical partiation (as I understand it, logical partitions will even be moved from one physical partition to another from time to time)

